# How to generate code from an openapi file?

Tags: quarkus, openapi-generator

is it possible to generate java code from the openapi definition file with quarkus?
Or should I use an external tool ?

Comment: explain what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator. I don't think Quarkus can do that.
Quarkus could generate an openapi yaml file from your quarkus project, which you could again use for openapi client generation.
For that take a look here https://quarkus.io/guides/openapi-swaggerui

Answer (score 0):

Quarkus itself won't do that for you. You need to use another tool.

Answer (score 0):

This project is now available: https://github.com/quarkiverse/quarkus-openapi-generator. Works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Quarkus now has:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkiverse.openapi.generator</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-openapi-generator</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus-openapi-generator.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-rest-client-jackson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

I also needed to update the quarkus maven plugin with the following (excuse the bad copy paste):

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>default-generate-code</id>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>generate-code</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <skipSourceGeneration>${skip.code-gen}</skipSourceGeneration>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
              <execution>
                <id>default-generate-code-tests</id>
                <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>generate-code-tests</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <skipSourceGeneration>${skip.code-gen}</skipSourceGeneration>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
              <execution>
                <id>default-build</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>build</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration></configuration>
          </plugin>
```

I then updated the maven compiler plugin:

```
          <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${compiler-plugin.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-compile</id>
            <configuration>
              <compilerArgs>
                <arg>-parameters</arg>
              </compilerArgs>
              <compileSourceRoots>
                <root>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</root>
                <root>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/open-api-json/net/xxx/billing/model/openapi/tmf629/model</root>
                <root>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/open-api-json/net/xxx/billing/model/openapi/tmf638/model</root>
                <root>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/open-api-json/net/xxx/billing/model/openapi/tmf639/model</root>
                <root>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/open-api-json/net/xxx/billing/model/openapi/tmf640/model</root>
              </compileSourceRoots>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```